# What is the path for my Jakarta EE app with Buildpack/Paketo?

Tags: tomcat, containers, jax-rs, buildpack, paketo

I wanted to test Paketo with a Jakarta EE 9 application (https://github.com/cwansart/qualified-injection-from-module-test) and ran:

```
pack build impl1 --builder paketobuildpacks/builder:base \
                 --env "BP_MAVEN_BUILT_ARTIFACT=controller/target/*.war"
```

After that I started the container with Docker:

```
docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 impl1
```

On my local Payara server I can reach the application on http://localhost:8080/controller/api/service, which does not work here. I am not sure where Tomcat published the app.

I checked the webapps folder inside the container. The application is there as it seems, but I can't find the correct context root.

Can someone tell me where the context root is or how I can find it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, different than I expected Tomcat does not fully support Jakarta EE 9. I had to add another dependency: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43382662/12550134

Comment: Correct. Tomcat only implements the Servlet, JSP, EL, WebSocket, and JASIC parts of the spec. If you require other parts, some of them you can pull in as JAR dependencies to your app as you did here. In other cases, you might need a full Jakarta EE server.